# How does change to the "verb" works?

Tags: verbs

As per my understanding `verb` changes as follow

- The sentence `I sing` changes to `He sings`
- The sentence `Do I sing`changes to `Does he sing?`

All, Good. But when I take a complex sentence like below

> "Symptoms of malaria `include` chills, fever and vomiting"

Question is: As per formula verb `include` shall change to `includes` for `it` (malaria ), like shown below. But i see below sentence is wrong. How is it?

> "Symptoms of malaria `includes` chills, fever and vomiting"

Comment: _Malaria_ is not the subject, so the verb doesn’t agree with it. _Symptoms of malaria_ is not an ‘it’, but a ‘they’. (And the reason why I used _is_ in the previous sentence instead of _are_ is that, even though the subject is still _symptoms of malaria_, in this case it’s really _the phrase ‘symptoms of malaria’_, which is singular.)

Comment: It is tough! Is there any easy way to make these decisions?

Comment: The general rule is that the _head_ of a noun phrase decides whether it is singular or plural. If there is a preposition with an object in the noun phrase, the object of the preposition is never the head, so in _symptoms [of malaria]_, the head is _symptoms_. This should be quite simple, because it works this way in most languages that distinguish singular/plural and allow noun phrases to contain PPs. The difficult part is that there are some NPs that **don’t** follow this rule, like _a lot of Xes_, which is plural, despite _a lot_ being singular.

Comment: Your examples switch from a first person subject ("I") to a third person subject ("he"). But your malaria sentence already has a third person plural subject. It is not structured like your other examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Symptoms' is a plural noun so the verb must be plural also.

Comment: @Michael Harvey , But right answer is to use "include", not "includes"

Comment: @kudlatiger Yes: *include* is the form of the verb which goes with plural subjects; the third-person singular form is *includes*.